# Javascript class import call expects exactly one argument

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

so I read a couple of question similar to mine but unfortunately it wasn't so similar or I just couldn't figure it out.
without further ado, this my export in Book.js

```
export default Book;
```

and my import in script.js

```
import Book from "./Book.js";
```

and link in html

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"> </script>
<script type="module" src="Book.js"> </script>
```

So basically how to fix class import call expects exactly one argument?
or just how to import the class and using it in main script properly ?

hope get approved and posted like it supposed to be ,
thanks in advance.

EDIT : SOLVED => for some reason it was not a code thing, I reseted dev tools in chrome and Firefox and everything worked.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sorry I thought it  was clear ,
how to fix the class import call expects exactly one argument error in console?
its just that my code works in safari but not in chrome or Firefox ..

Comment: Solved it , I made a reset for both browsers dev tools , thanks for your time!